# What do the '&&' and star '**' symbols mean in Rust?

Tags: pointers, rust, borrow

```rust
fn main() {
    let c: i32 = 5;
    let rrc = &&c;
    println!("{}", rrc); // 5
    println!("{}", *rrc); // 5
    println!("{}", **rrc); // 5
}
```

In C/C++ language, rrc likes a two level pointer. In this example, rrc doesn't mean this in rust. What do `&` and `*` mean in Rust?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason they all print the same thing is that borrows (`&T`) in Rust implements `Display` for `T: Display` by [dispatching it to the pointed type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/fmt/mod.rs.html#2371). If you want to print the actual pointer value, you have to use `{:p}`.

```rust
let c = 5;
let rrc = &&c;
println!("{:p}", rrc); // 0x7ffc4e4c7590
println!("{:p}", *rrc); // 0x7ffc4e4c7584
println!("{}", **rrc); // 5
```

See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5ff696747fe5274559aabbbbe37d374c).

Answer (score 3):

It is simply two reference operators. The reason why they all print 5 is because when printing a reference it automatically de-references it:

```rust
fn main() {
  let c: i32 = 5;
  let rrc = &c;
  let rrc = &rrc; // this is &&c
}
```